# setting Postgres options during a pg_restore

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-15

I am finding it difficult to find the best way to set Postgres options for a pg_restore session only. It would be nice to be able to do this in the environment in which I run pg_restore and not change global sessions or have to initiate an interactive psql session. E.g. I would like to set these values during the restore only.

```
 work_mem = 32MB
 shared_buffers = 4GB
 maintenance_work_mem = 2GB
 full_page_writes = off
 autovacuum = off
 wal_buffers = -1
```

I did try using `export PGOPTIONS` for the values, but I am not sure it actually worked or whether the format for setting them was correct, e.g. `export PGOPTIONS='-c work_mem=32MB -c shared_buffers=4GB'` etc.

Comment: As a test in a session do  `export PGOPTIONS='-c work_mem=32MB -c shared_buffers=4GB'` then open `psql` and run show `show all;` to see if the settings took.

Comment: A change in shared_buffers requires a restart of the PostgreSQL service. You can't do that in pg_restore. Same thing for some other settings

Comment: ok, makes sense, so it's just easier to restart the service with new options for the duration of the imports and then restart it again using prior settings?

Comment: What is the problem you try to solve?

Comment: What file format (custom, text or directory)?  Can you restart Postgresql?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the parameters you want to set don't make any sense. Here is my recommendation:

- increase `max_wal_size` a lot
- increase `maintenance_work_mem` a lot
- set `wal_level = minimal` and use `--single-transaction` with `pg_restore`, so that PostgreSQL can skip writing WAL

The first two options can be set via `PGOPTIONS` like you show in your question, the third requires changing parameters in the configuration file or on the server command line and a restart.

To see if `PGOPTIONS` works, try

```bash
PGOPTIONS="-c work_mem=123MB" psql -c "SHOW work_mem"
```

Comment: Increasing `maintenance_work_mem` is a bad idea if you have many jobs.  The recommendation is to **reduce** `maintenance_work_mem`, so that every job (and it's worker threads) can have `maintenance_work_mem` RAM.

Comment: @RonJohn Think again.

Comment: A Josh Berkus blog post: https://www.databasesoup.com/2014/09/settings-for-fast-pgrestore.html "However, since we're doing concurrent restore, you don't want to get carried away; **your limit should be (RAM/(2*concurrency)), in order to maintain somewhat of an FS buffer**."

Comment: @RonJohn I see what you are saying. Well, increasing `maintenance_work_mem` is a good idea for speeding up `pg_restore`, but you shouldn't set it so high that you start swapping or going OOM. Perhaps I should have mentioned that, but I thought it was clear. I don't agree with Josh that having a lot of kernel page cache will speed up `pg_restore`, but perhaps there is some aspect I don't realize.

Comment: I'm currently experimenting with parameters on migrating a 4TB db from 9.6 to 14.  (The metadata is large, complicated -- inheritance partitioning -- and frequently changes, so logical replication is impractical.)  25% (32GB) shared_buffers, 2GB main_work_mem and 30 threads hits swap pretty hard.  Dropping to 24 threads slowed things down, and *still* hit swap.

Comment: And these are VMs on busy ESX hosts, so who knows what the heck is going on in the background... :(

Comment: @RonJohn If you start swapping, it is game over.

Answer (score 0):

If you can restart Postgresql (I didn't see you mention one way or another), you can pass *ad hoc* parameters there.

For example:

```
pg_ctl restart -wt9999 -mfast \
                -o "-c hba_file=/var/lib/pgsql/14/data/pg_hba_maintmode.conf" \
                -o "-c fsync=off" \
                -o "-c log_statement=none" \
                -o "-c log_temp_files=100kB" \
                -o "-c log_checkpoints=off" \
                -o "-c log_min_duration_statement=120000" \
                -o "-c maintenance_work_mem=2GB" \
                -o "-c synchronous_commit=off" \
                -o "-c archive_mode=off" \
                -o "-c full_page_writes=off" \
                -o "-c checkpoint_timeout=30min" \
                -o "-c max_wal_size=36GB" \
                -o "-c wal_level=minimal" \
                -o "-c max_wal_senders=0" \
                -o "-c wal_buffers=64MB" \
                -o "-c autovacuum=off"
```

Then do the `pg_restore`, `vacuumdb --analyze-only` and lastly `pg_ctl stop -wt9999 -mfast && pg_ctl start -wt9999`.

(The explicit stop/start are required because `pg_ctl restart` retains the passed parameters, while stop/start wipes them out.)